# Rails error serving assets

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, webrick

I am migrating a big site from Rails 2 to Rails 3. When I try to get an asset I get the following error using `Webrick`:

```
Started GET "/assets/key.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-20 11:00:06 -0300
Served asset /key.png - 200 OK (15ms)
[2013-03-20 11:00:08] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:71:in `service'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

I have checked rack source code and the problem is in the following line of the file webrick.rb (body is nil):

```
body.each { |part|
        res.body << part
      }
```

Using `Thin` I get a similar error:

```
Started GET "/assets/key.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-20 11:34:31 -0300
Served asset /key.png - 200 OK (33ms)
!! Rack application returned nil body. Probably you wanted it to be an empty string?
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

And in the browser:

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

I have been struggling with this error. Any help??

Comment: Perhaps you should try updating rack to a newer version?

Comment: How can I do it? I also tried with passenger and it didnt work. But let me know how to update rack.

Comment: I would say `gem update rack` :)

Comment: Also, I've read many times that [Thin is faster than Webrick](http://www.psteiner.com/2012/04/how-to-replace-webrick-with-thin-for.html), perhaps you could try it too?

Comment: The gem is updated but rails is still using the old one. I suspect that It wont work with Thin but I will give it a shot

Comment: Same error in thin. Check my updated question

Comment: Is your `key.png` empty?

Comment: Any other ideas Nebelman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was something related to memcache. I dont have it installed.

I just commented the following line:

config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it has to do with a missing memcache server. In my case I found that Heroku also publishes instructions for setting up a quick little memcached server for the purpose of duplicating your production env locally.